Assuming A is an $m\times m$ matrix of rank $r < m$, and $Ax=0$ for some $x \neq 0$, prove that $x$ can't be written as linear combo of columns of $A$
I know that if $Ax=0$ where $x\neq0$ then $x$ is in the null space of $A$, but then how do i show that it can't be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$? Or am i asking something very stupid?
Im getting stuck trying to prove it:
Given: $Ax = 0$; $A$ is $m\times m$, $x$ is $m \times 1$, and $x \neq 0$
Assume $$\vec{x}=\sum^{m}_{i=1}{c_i.\vec{a}_{i}}$$
where ai's are the columns of A, and ci's are some constants (essentially assuming x can be represented as a linear combo of columns of A).
Now just re writing the above
$$x = A.\vec{c} $$
Hence:
$$ A.\vec{x} = A.A.\vec{c} = 0 $$
Now how do i proceed? Im unable to find the contradiction

I don't think what you are proposing is true. Let $m = 2$ and consider the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then, $A\vec{x} = 0$, but clearly we can write $\vec{x}$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Thats a good counter-example. When I read the question, I thought there is something fishy here and there should be a counter-example for sure. I was trying some 3x3 matrices but couldn't find it. We can think this geometrically, that is we know that null space is perpendicular to row space. Now if column space is also perpendicular to row space, we can say null space is same as column space (in 2 dimensions only. Not true for higher dimensions). This is what your example is doing as well.

Thank you for the example. i see that what i proposed was wrong. But I do have another doubt, does this mean that in general $N(A) \cap C(A) \neq 0$? and is there a way to prove this with a non counter-example technique?

Its not always true. In some cases there can be no elements in common (other than zero vector). For example we know that row space and null space are perpendicular and only have zero vector as common. Now if row space is same as column space then we will no common elements in column space and null space other than zero vector.  An example for this would be a symmetric matrix as row space is same as column space.
